# Relation of Digital Logic Design to Electrical Power Engineering?

Tags: electrical-engineering

I'm an undergraduate student of Electrical Power Engineering currently in 3rd semester, one of the courses we  study is Digital Logic Design(dld) and I have found much interest in it but I am unclear whether the subject would have application in our field i.e. power engineering or not....Could anyone guide me that how should I study dld with what things in mind related to future perspective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a job description for a Senior Electrical Engineer position at Princeton power systems to help you with future perspective. [Princeton Power System](https://web.archive.org/web/20220331101227/https://princetonpower.com/) makes power inverters for the Renewable Energy market. As you would see few key words that address the relationship between Digital Logic Design and Electrical Power Engineering.

- FPGA – Field Programmable Gate Array
- Power Electronics
- Microprocessors

---

> **Senior Electrical Engineer**
>
> *Job Description:* You will be a key member of the Product Development
> team developing state of the art Power Conversion products for use in
> Alternative Energy, Renewable Energy, Energy Storage, Micro-Grid, and
> Backup Power applications. Tasks will include design of power
> conversion systems, design of electrical control circuitry,
> development of control algorithms and software, performing
> system-level analysis and design, printed circuit board design, and
> supporting fabrication and testing of components and systems.
>
> Responsibilities:
>
> - Control system and auxiliary electronics circuits design
> - Overall system architecture and schematic design
> - Printed circuit board design and design supervision
> - Simulation or analysis of electronic circuits ranging from small electronics to high-power electronics
> - Software development for **microprocessor** and **FPGA**-based control
>   systems and PC-based graphical user interfaces
> - Electrical system test procedure development, testing, and test reporting
> - Analysis of system design reliability and design for reliability
> - Generation of electrical schematics and manufacturing-related documentation
>
> Required:
>
> - At least a Bachelor’s degree in Engineering or other pertinent field.
> - Detailed understanding of modern electrical engineering principles and practice
> - Experience with printed circuit board design
>
> Ideal:
>
> - Experience with high-**power electronics**
> - Software development experience
> - Experience with system simulation

Most of [Supervisory control and data acquisition (SCADA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCADA) have microprocessor and/or FPGA, thus the close relationship between Digital Logic Design and Electrical Power Engineering.

Hope this helps with some ideas related to future perspective and the relationship between Digital Logic Design and Electrical Power Engineering. Investigating Renewable Energy Industry and power electronics related supervisory control system might be a good start.

---

**References:**

- [FPGA implementation of a fastflex supervisory control and data acquisition (SCADA) remote telemetry unit](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1569247)
- [RTU hardware design for SCADA systems using FPGA](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5735058)

Answer (score 0):

Having studied electronic and electrical engineering, I covered both the power/analogue and the digital part. There were certain power designs where using a digital microcontroller (to generate a square wave of a certain time period and duty ratio) helped.

There are methods of obtaining oscillators using discrete analogue components (a Wien Bridge oscillator), but incorporating a 555 timer (digital) makes things much simpler.

Digital Electronics are used in systems control, so it still has relevance to eletrical engineering.

Digital Logic Design and VLSI technology were still my favourite topics as it shows how the theoretical boolean logic is implemented using hardware a nano-scale.